# Android studio - error : requires API level 14

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

Android keeps complaining

[image]

I made sure my manifest settings are set to 14

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.xxxxxxxx.yyyyyyyyyy.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.xxxxxxxxxxxx.yyyyyyy.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.xxxxxxxxxxxx.yyyyyyy.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCompatTheme">
    </activity>
</application>
```

**gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```

Comment: maybe you opened the wrong manifest? wait a bit? don't care because the compiler still works?

Comment: Could you post the rest of your manifest?

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: I tried that bro, I also synced gradle

Comment: @Tukajo posted see edit

Comment: Lets see your gradle file

Comment: added the gradle as well

Comment: Make your targeted sdk version match your targeted sdk version in both your gradle and manifest

Comment: Maybe not realted but.. Is this normal targetSdkVersion 17 in your gradle if your manifest has 19?

Comment: then try cleaning and recompiling